# How to attach new fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to open new fragment over my existing fragment but I wont able to do so can anybody I have attached my code please help

This is my LoginFragment and replace it BookingHistoryFragment

```
String statusCode = response.getString("statusCode");
if (statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
    // get token and start your flow
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag");
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? what is the error ? please make a clearer question. To attach a fragment to an activity you need to use a Transaction.

Comment: Sounds like your status code is not ok

Comment: Answer given by @Praful is fine but I suggest using the Navigation Architecture Component. It will be super easy for you.

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.detach(LoginFragment.this).attach(BookingHistoryFragment.this).commit();  

I have used this but it is giving error on BookingHistoryFragment saying it is not an enclosing class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to open fragment to activity

```
public void onFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.home_frag, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: how to find id of my "R.id.home_frag"

Comment: this is id of fragment view of activity.

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); ft.detach(LoginFragment.this).attach(BookingHistoryFragment.this).commit(); I have used this but it is giving error on BookingHistoryFragment saying it is not an enclosing class

Comment: OnFragmentInteractionListener

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar in my application.
To do this, First I have added both the fragment inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.middle_layout, normalMatchFragment).commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.middle_layout, 
    infinityMatchFragmnet).commit();
    }
```

And then call changeFragment(boolean isNormalFragmnet) method whenever you want to switch the fragments.

```
    public void changeFragment(boolean isNormalFragmnet) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (isNormalFragmnet) {
        isNoramFragment = true;
        transaction.hide(infinityMatchFragmnet);
        transaction.show(normalMatchFragment);
    } else {
        isNoramFragment = false;
        transaction.hide(normalMatchFragment);
        transaction.show(infinityMatchFragmnet);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```